# Debug failed kubernetes deployment

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I am experimenting with Kubernetes on Digital Ocean.
As a testcase, i am trying to deploy a Jenkins instance to my cluster with a persistent volume.

My deployment yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jenkins-deployment
  labels:
    app: jenkins
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jenkins
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jenkins
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: jenkins
        image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
        volumeMounts:
          - name: jenkins-home
            mountPath: /var/jenkins_home
      volumes:
        - name: jenkins-home
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: jenkins-pvc
```

My PV Claim

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: jenkins-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: do-block-storage
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 30Gi
```

For some reason the pod keeps ending up in a `CrashLoopBackOff` state.

`kubectl describe pod <podname>` gives me

```
Name:           jenkins-deployment-bb5857d76-j2f2w
Namespace:      default
Priority:       0
Node:           cc-pool-bg6c/10.138.123.186
Start Time:     Sun, 15 Sep 2019 22:18:56 +0200
Labels:         app=jenkins
                pod-template-hash=bb5857d76
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Running
IP:             10.244.0.166
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/jenkins-deployment-bb5857d76
Containers:
  jenkins:
    Container ID:   docker://4eaadebb917001d8d3eaaa3b043e1b58b6269f929b9e95c4b08d88b0098d29d6
    Image:          jenkins/jenkins:lts
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://jenkins/jenkins@sha256:7cfe34701992434cc08bfd40e80e04ab406522214cf9bbefa57a5432a123b340
    Port:           8080/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Sun, 15 Sep 2019 22:35:14 +0200
      Finished:     Sun, 15 Sep 2019 22:35:14 +0200
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  8
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/jenkins_home from jenkins-home (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-wd6p7 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  jenkins-home:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  jenkins-pvc
    ReadOnly:   false
  default-token-wd6p7:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-wd6p7
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age                  From                     Message
  ----     ------                  ----                 ----                     -------
  Normal   Scheduled               19m                  default-scheduler        Successfully assigned default/jenkins-deployment-bb5857d76-j2f2w to cc-pool-bg6c
  Normal   SuccessfulAttachVolume  19m                  attachdetach-controller  AttachVolume.Attach succeeded for volume "pvc-cb772fdb-492b-4ef5-a63e-4e483b8798fd"
  Normal   Pulled                  17m (x5 over 19m)    kubelet, cc-pool-bg6c    Container image "jenkins/jenkins:lts" already present on machine
  Normal   Created                 17m (x5 over 19m)    kubelet, cc-pool-bg6c    Created container jenkins
  Normal   Started                 17m (x5 over 19m)    kubelet, cc-pool-bg6c    Started container jenkins
  Warning  BackOff                 4m8s (x72 over 19m)  kubelet, cc-pool-bg6c    Back-off restarting failed container
```

Could anyone help me point out what is wrong here, or where to look for that matter?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the output of `kubectl logs jenkins-deployment-bb5857d76-j2f2w`?

Comment: touch: cannot touch '/var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log': Permission denied
Can not write to /var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log. Wrong volume permissions? => so this seems to be a permission problem?

Comment: Yes, it is a permission problem. Look at the solution I posted below and tell me if that solves your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you don't have permission to write to the volume.
Try running the container as root using security contexts:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jenkins-deployment
  labels:
    app: jenkins
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jenkins
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jenkins
    spec:
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1000 
        runAsUser: 0
      containers:
      - name: jenkins
        image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
        volumeMounts:
          - name: jenkins-home
            mountPath: /var/jenkins_home
      volumes:
        - name: jenkins-home
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: jenkins-pvc
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! Not sure if its a good idea to run containers as root though. For now it does work.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot add comment (not enough reputation :D)

Looking at the pod logs may give some idea `kubectl logs <podname>`

PVC seems to be allocated and attached without issues. I had similar issues deploying `nginx` container a while ago, the issue was `nginx` container requires specific UID on host to work. Check if `jenkins` container needs specific UID.

Also, you may need to set required permissions on the volume (depending on jenkins requirement).